# Using Map<String, String> with an AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want my AutocompleteTextView to display data in a rather different way.

Support I have the following map:

> Home : ABC
>   Office: DEF
>   School: GHI

Now if the user types in 'Home' in the AutocompleteTextView, it should show ABC in the dropdown.

Is it possible to achieve the above functionality without using a custom Adapter?

Comment: whats the purpose of that if you have only 3 entries in your adapter? why not to use a `Spinner`?

Comment: That was just an example.. I have a lot more entries.

Comment: and what if you have `Home` and `Hospital` and the user types `Ho`?

Comment: Both Home and Hospital should be shown, like any normal Autocomplete query.

Comment: then use `FilterQueryProvider`, something similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: and how? did it work?